# Increement issue in android

Tags: android

I want to increase the value of "unit" in my question

```
public void fetchunit()
{
    CardDatabase carddb =new CardDatabase(getApplicationContext());
    carddb.open();

    Cursor c=carddb.selectAll();

//  c.moveToFirst();

     c.moveToFirst();
    int count = c.getCount();
        Log.e("card", c.getString(0));

        inflateRecord(c.getString(0),c.getString(1));
        c.moveToNext();

        unit=c.getString(0);

        c.close();
    carddb.close();
}
int count;
public void getunit()
{
    CardDatabase carddb =new CardDatabase(getApplicationContext());
    carddb.open();
    Cursor c=carddb.getrecord(unit);

//  c.moveToFirst();

    // c.moveToFirst();
     count = c.getCount();
        Log.e("card", c.getString(0));
        inflateRecord(c.getString(0),c.getString(1));
        c.moveToNext();

        c.close();
    carddb.close();


}
```

when i call getunit() there is no incremeant in "unit"....so its always give a same value when i call getunit()

```
public void bottom2top(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.img3:

            getunit();


    break;

     }
}
```

pleas suggest me what to do...thank to all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you close the cursor using `c.close()` you lose any information about the position of the cursor.

You should either:

- retreive a specific record using a primary key

OR

- retrieve all records and return them as an ArrayList